# Unit testing a Tapestry 4 page (Currently using Mockito; any drawbacks to my approach?)

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, tapestry

What is a good way to unit test a Tapestry 4 page?

So far, this is what I have, which seems to work well: I am using Mockito to mock the tapestry page class, and then using doCallRealMethod() to access the real method I want to test.  I'm wondering if Tapestry 4 offers a more integrated solution, like Tapestry 5 would.  However, this solution seems to be rather good.

As a secondary question, are there any hidden drawbacks to this approach?

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public void testTapestryPage() {
   //setup
   MyTapestryPage partiallyMockedTapestryPage = mock(MyTapestryPage.class);

   //exercise    
   doCallRealMethod().when(partiallyMockedTapestryPage).someMethod(); /*Working around abstract class and tapestry pain.*/
   partiallyMockedTapestryPage.someMethod();

   //verify
    ...
}
```

Comment: I feel this question would be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.  The questions on  Stack Overflow are more about finding solutions to things that don't work.

Comment: But, yes, this approach looks perfectly good to me.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Thanks, didn't know about the code review site.  Any idea how to move it there?